# jackson writes to file with special characters

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to serialize my `MoneyOperation` objects into json format. I managed to write all data I need to external file, but output is full of special characters `\r\n , \` and I don't want them in my file. Also I used `DefaultPrettyPrinter` on `ObjectWriter` to make my serialized data readable.

First I write value as follows:

`getMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);`

Then I make `sysout` on it, the output is:

```
{
  "monetaryAmount" : "CHF 90000",
  "description" : " bougth transport car",
  "date" : "2018-05-12",
  "type" : {
    "type" : "OUTCOME",
    "source" : "BILL"
  }
}
```

Then I simply call:

`writer.writeValue(file, jsonObjectsToSave);`

But while writing it to file, I get:

```
"{\r\n  \"monetaryAmount\" : \"CHF 90000\",\r\n  \"description\" : \" bougth transport car\",\r\n  \"date\" : \"2018-05-12\",\r\n  \"type\" : {\r\n    \"type\" : \"OUTCOME\",\r\n    \"source\" : \"BILL\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

How do I fix this output?

Comment: Turn off pretty printing in the writer.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to write the output to the file? I suspect you're accidentally encoding the output as a JSON *string* before writing it. Please also show your *expected* output.

Answer (score 1):

The `\r\n` is what makes it readable (newlines), which is what you're seeing that in your string, if you disable pretty printing when you write to the file it will not display those characters.

Comment: And how about backshlashes? Are they mandatory? If not, is there an option to write to file without them?